# Seeking advice on how to stop a Timer used in a LinearProgressIndicator

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a LinearProgressIndicator to visually display a countdown of time and trigger a function at certain intervals. I am doing this by updating the LinearProgressIndicator's `value` prop using a state variable `_progress` that gets decremented by 0.01 each 100 milliseconds.
When I set conditions that were based on two decimal points, or even 0 `if (_progress == 0.75)`, I discovered that the conditions were being skipped because the value of _progress was quickly becoming a much larger fraction that would not match my condition (e.g. 0.7502987777777). I assume this is an inherent issue of working with doubles, but my question then becomes, what is the best way to deal with this if you want to trigger actions based on the value of _progress? My approach is to broaden the conditions - for example `if (_progress > 0.75 && _progress < 0.76)`.

Any tips/advice would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with floating-point values, you often cannot depend on strict equality.  Instead you should check if the floating-point value you have is within a certain *tolerance* of the desired value.  One approach:

```dart
bool closeTo(double value1, double value2, [double epsilon = 0.001]) =>
  (value1 - value2).abs() <= epsilon;

if (closeTo(_progress, 0.75)) {
  // Do something.
}
```

([`package:matcher`](https://pub.dev/documentation/matcher/latest/matcher/closeTo.html) has a similar [`closeTo`](https://pub.dev/documentation/matcher/latest/matcher/closeTo.html) function for matching values in tests.)

Arguably, since floating-point values are *floating*, your tolerance should depend on the magnitude of the values.

In your case, you alternatively should strongly consider avoiding floating-point values for internal state: use fixed-point values by multiplying everything by 100 and using `int`s instead.  That is, let `_progress` be an `int`, decrement it by 1 every 100 ms, and then you can compare against 75 or other values directly and exactly.  This additionally would have the advantage of not accumulating floating-point error when you repeatedly decrement `_progress`.  If you need to present `_progress` to the user or pass it to `LinearProgressIndicator`, use `_progress / 100` instead.

Comment: Doooh!!  That makes so much more sense. I simply changed _progress to an int starting at 100 and decremented by 1 each 100 milliseconds, then used _progress/100 in the LinearProgressIndicator. That allowed me to use integers in the if statement ```if (_progress == 75)``` and it worked like a charm. Thanks for taking the time to help me think differently. Much appreciated.